# Jquery/Html5 function issue double click issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm new in HTML5 / JqueryMobile.
I have this function, but for some strange reason, it gives me the result the second time I call, by Onclick(), here is my code :

```js
function ListDBValues() {
  if (!window.openDatabase) { 
    alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.'); 
    return; 
 }
$('#lbUsers').html(''); 
db.transaction(function(transaction) { 
   transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM productos order by titulo;', [], 
   function(transaction, result) { 
      if (result != null && result.rows != null) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) { 
          var row = result.rows.item(i); 
          $('#lbUsers').append('<div id="producto"><img id="imgprod" width="100" src="images/' + row.foto +'">' + row.recid + '.' + row.titulo + '<br>$' + row.precio + ' MXP<br><input class="cuadro" type="button" id="cb.row" name="item"  value="ORDENAR" onclick=AddValueToOrders(' + row.recid + ');></div>');

        } 
      } 
     },errorHandler); 
 },errorHandler,nullHandler);
 return; 
}
```

This is the second Function :

```js
 function AddValueToOrders(item) {  
    if (!window.openDatabase) { 
      alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.'); 
      return; 
    } 
    msga = "El item es: "+ item ;
    alert(msga);
    db.transaction(function(tx) { 
        /// veo si ya existe /////

        tx.executeSql('SELECT count(*) AS c FROM orders where prodid = '+ item +'  ', [], 
        function (tx, result) { 
               totprod = result.rows.item(0).c;
               //totprod = results.rows.item(0)['c'];

        });
    });

    var themessage = "Total producto: ";
    themessage = themessage + totprod ;
    alert(themessage);                 

}
```

The thing is I want to know if the product already exist on the Orders table, so I can update it, and not insert another product of the same code.

Comment: not sure why do you reference click and double click, if you are on mobile wouldn't you be using the tap event?, I can read from your code you are doing some transactions you should be doing your alerts inside the callback function which are asynchronous and won't follow execution order from the rest of the function logic. 

Please update your answer with a better description of what you are doing and are you expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but I refactored your code and added some comments, you should also check my original comment on your question,

```
function ListDBValues() {
    if (!window.openDatabase) { 
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.'); 
        return; 
    }
    $('#lbUsers').html(''); 
    db.transaction(function(transaction) { 
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM productos order by titulo;', [], 
        function(transaction, result) { 
            if (result != null && result.rows != null) { 
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) { 
                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                    // changed the append logic
                    // created new dom object w/jQuery
                    // bind tap event
                    // execute function on tap
                    // append to dom
                    $('<div id="producto"><img id="imgprod" width="100" src="images/' + row.foto +'">' + row.recid + '.' + row.titulo + '<br>$' + row.precio + ' MXP<br><input class="cuadro" type="button" id="cb.row" name="item"  value="ORDENAR"></div>').data( 'recid', row.recid ).bind('tap', function(){
                        AddValueToOrders( $(this).data('recid') );
                    }).appendTo('#lbUsers');
                } 
            } 
        }, errorHandler); 
    }, errorHandler, nullHandler);
    return; 
}
function AddValueToOrders(item) {  
    if (!window.openDatabase) { 
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.'); 
        return; 
    } 
    msga = "El item es: "+ item ;
    alert(msga);
    db.transaction(function(tx) { 
        /// veo si ya existe /////
        tx.executeSql('SELECT count(*) AS c FROM orders where prodid = '+ item +'  ', [], 
        function (tx, result) { 
            totprod = result.rows.item(0).c;
            //totprod = results.rows.item(0)['c'];
            alert("Total producto: " + totprod);
            // you can do your insert here depending on 
            // the value you got back from this checkpoint
        });
    });
}
```

please let me know if this works better.

**UPDATE:**
Also you are using ID's on the elements you are creating on the for loop, you should know this will create conflicts as ID's are meant to be unique, you might wan't to change them to classes

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, it works like I was expecting to work. And you're right, maybe I'm not thinking like a mobile app, I'm thinking like a web app, so I need to study more ..., thanks again